# Why I get error parsing JSON when get from Feign?

Tags: java, jackson, feign, fasterxml

Here is my JSON I'm returning from my STUB:

```
{
  "brokerAccounts": [
     {
       "id": "4598",
       "customTags": [
         "main-buy"
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Here is the java class for an entity

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class InvestBrokerAccountsRs {
    private List<InvestBrokerAccount> brokerAccounts;

    @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class InvestBrokerAccount {
        private String id;
        private List<String> customTags;
    }
}
```

After trying to get it using Feign `ResponseEntity<String>` I'm getting this:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
```

As I see, my json is valid. I have the `@Data` annotation which provides getters and setters. What is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like to me that this is responsible - `ResponseEntity<String>`. You are trying to deserialize your json, which is in json **object** format into a string, which is not possible, since **string** format is different.

I think changing to:

```
ResponseEntity<InvestBrokerAccountsRs>
```

should fix your problem.